# Is it possible to use computed fields within JSON with ObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, json, swift, http, objectmapper

If I have an object like so:

```
class Order: BaseEntity {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        name      <- map["name"]
        age       <- map["address"]
        condition() <- map["condition"]
    }

    func condition() -> String {
        ... do something here
    }
}
```

How can i map an attribute that is not a get/set property. it could be a constant, a fucntion or a read-only property. is this possible?